# how to use javascript regex to remove characters from string

Tags: javascript

I have a string value which would look like the following with sample

```
data:


130823  ~ Optics-Bottle Detect failure ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | 130824 ~ Optics-Bubble Detect failure ~ L 0 ~ P 0

Format:

ID:          130823
Description: Optics-Bottle Detect failure 
Reps:        L O
Pending:     P 0
```

My final string should basically remove the ID from each part in the concatenated string so by looking at the above sample data the desired output should be as follows:

```
 Optics-Bottle Detect failure ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | Optics-Bubble Detect failure ~ L 0 ~ P 0
```

There could be **N** number of parts in one string.  For the sake of example I only included a sample string which has two parts in it.

**My Regex

Im using the following regular expression but it only removed the ID from the first part in the string

```
var y = x.replace(/\d{6}\s~\s/g, "");
```

Comment: This is removing both IDs from the string above for me.

Comment: That removes both: http://jsfiddle.net/6KkGK/

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bbsss/

Comment: @RocketHazmat I corrected my sample data string. There was an issue earlier. With this sample data it will not return correctly

Comment: @nnnnnn  I corrected my sample data string. There was an issue earlier. With this sample data it will not return correctly

Comment: `130823  ~`  There are 2 spaces after the number, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string into a multidimensional array using the delimiters `" | "` and `" ~ "`.  Then you can `.shift()` off the id, since it is the first entry in the array, and join it all back together:

```
var y = x.split(" | ").map(function(s) {
    s = s.split(" ~ ");
    s.shift();
    return s.join(" ~ ");
}).join(" | ");
```

Or, get the substring after the `" ~ "`:

```
var y = x.split(" | ").map(function(s) {
    return s.substr(s.indexOf(" ~ ") + 3);
}).join(" | ");
```

Or, correct your RegExp to account for whitespace length variation:

```
var y = x.replace(/\d{6}\s+~\s/g, "");
```

But, this RegExp will only work as long as there are always exactly 6 digits in the id, and never 6 digits preceding a `~` elsewhere.  For example, if there should ever be a value for `Reps` of 100000 or more, your RegExp will remove that as well.

A better regular expression would take any number of digits (more *or* less than 6) and would only match it if it's the first item, or follows a `|`:

```
var y = x.replace(/(^|\|\s+)\d+\s+~\s+/g, "$1");
```

Comment: The ids could go past 6 digits very well since its a identity column value for rows. Should I just use the first function you have listed in the answer above.

Comment: Yes, either of the first two solutions would work better, assuming `id` always comes first in each entry.  I'll update my answer with a more robust regular expression option as well, if you prefer that option.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible answer, for example

```
var str = "144515 ~ Commodities-Damaged Reagent Cartridge ~ L 0 ~ P 0 | 144516 ~ Commodities";
var n=/\d{6}\s+~/g;
str = str.replace(n, "");
```

Comment: This does not remove the `~`.